# Modal not fading after applying bootswatch theme

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

I applied the "Spacelab" theme from bootswatch and now the webpage does not fade out behind the popup.

Code in View:

```
<body>

<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#article-editor1" data-toggle="modal">Add Building</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="article-editor1" draggable="true" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h4>Building Information</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="tesing">Building Name: </td>
                <td id="tesing">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.siteName)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="tesing">Building Size:</td>
                <td id="tesing">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.siteSize)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="tesing">Zipcode: </td>
                <td id="tesing">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.siteZip)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="tesing">Cooling Setpoint:</td>
                <td id="tesing">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.siteOccClg)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="tesing">Heating Setpoint:</td>
                <td id="tesing">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.siteOccHtg)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

code in css:

```
.modal-backdrop.fade {
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);

  opacity: 0;
}
.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I have compared the modal & fade sections to the original bootsrap CSS file and found no differences.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own problem. The version of boostrap that the theme was using was setting the backdrop to a "0" height
See Dubug:

```
 // Modal background
 .modal-backdrop {
-  position: fixed;
+  position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
-  bottom: 0;
```

so I edited the CSS to comment out the "top" property and added a height property of 100% as shown here:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 0;*/
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #b94a48;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height:100% /*Add This*/
}
```